# Secure enigma machine?

Tags: enigma

The enigma machine had a serious flaw: the letters could not be encrypted as themselves. Is there an online enigma simulator I can try that does not have this flaw, which would likely make it secure?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the [Typex machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typex).

It was developed by the British and it had the major design flaw of the Enigma machine removed, which was the fixed-point-free permutation, meaning that no letter will be encrypted to itself.

A Typex simulator can be downloaded on [Github (released by GCHQ)](https://github.com/gchq/CyberChef/wiki/Enigma,-the-Bombe,-and-Typex). Unfortunately I could not find an online simulator, but maybe you'll have more luck.

Comment: It also had more irregular stepping, which made it better.